# Adding a file to local git repository, then pushing to remote: doesn't work

Tags: git, github

I am *very* new to Git/github.

I set up a git repo (actually migrated from another version control system), and used:

/C/homedir

```
$ git init
```

I got now that /c/homedir is my master.

I pushed to my remote github server.

This pushed *only the tracked files* to the remote repo.

I added a new file to the local master repo in a subdirectory:

/C/homedir/somedir (master)

```
$ git add <file>
$ git commit -m "comment"
```

If I am in a subdirectory trying to push using:

/C/homedir/somedir (master)

```
$ git push origin master
```

it says

> fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could
>   not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

And if I push to remote from the original directory:

/C/homedir/ (master)

```
$ git push origin master
```

it says

> Everything up-to-date

**Question: How do I push the new file to the remote repo?**

---

Edit: I have done the commit (forgot to write it; now fixed). Problem still persists.

**Problem solved**: a hidden .git file was present in the sub directory.

Comment: At first, You always need to commit your changes after `git add <file>` with `git commit -m <short commit description here>` after that you don't need to push from your subdirectory, just go to home directory and then push

Comment: `git push` sends *commits*, not files. Commits *contain* files but you have not yet made a new commit; none of the *existing* commits contain that file.

Comment: Thanks. I did the commit (forgot to write it; now fixed). Problem still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

The crux of the matter is that there was an additional (hidden) .git file in the subdirectory \somedir !

This then caused the following:

If I am in a subdirectory trying to push using:

/C/homedir/somedir (master)

```
$ git push origin master
```

it says

> fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git >repository fatal: Could not read from remote >repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you forgot to make a commit

```
git commit -m "my first commit"
```

https://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial

Comment: Thanks you! I did the commit (forgot to write it; now fixed). Problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

At first, You always need to commit your changes after `git add <file>` with

```
git commit -m <short commit description here>
```

after that you don't need to push from your subdirectory, just go to the home directory and then push

[git commit docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)

Comment: Thanks you! I did the commit (forgot to write it; now fixed). Problem still persists.

Comment: did you do the commit from home directory?

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure you need to commit always from the home directory? Very strange. Anyway, I have solved the problem now: there was a hidden .git file in the subdirectory!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I always do that

Answer (score 0):

You missed one important step. The "commit" step. After adding the files, you need to commit these before pushing it to the remote repository.

```
git commit -m <description>
```

You may check out this [link](https://opensource.com/article/18/1/step-step-guide-git).

Comment: Thanks you! I did the commit (forgot to write it; now fixed). Problem still persists.